# How to run a local bat file on a remote computer

Tags: windows, remote, psexec

Is it possible to use psexec to run a local bat file on a remote computer (windows 7)? or would I have to first copy it over to the remote location and then run it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would suggest using [psexec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) which is part of the SysInternals Suite.

```
psexec \\remotemachine -u remoteuser -i -d cmd -c localdisk:\folder\batchfile.bat
```

*`-c` will copy from local path*

Answer (score 0):

You can use WMIC or SCHTASKS:

1) [SCHTASKS](http://ss64.com/nt/schtasks.html):

```
SCHTASKS /s remote_machine /U username /P password /create /tn "On demand demo" /tr "C:\some.bat" /sc ONCE /sd 01/01/1910 /st 00:00
SCHTASKS /s remote_machine /U username /P password /run /TN "On demand demo"
```

2) [WMIC](http://ss64.com/nt/wmic.html) (wmic will return the pid of the started process)

```
WMIC /NODE remote_machine /user user /password password process call create "c:\some.bat","c:\exec_dir"
```